# How do I design a schema to handle periodic bulk inserts/updates?

Tags: mysql, database-design, import, amazon-web-services

(tldr; I think that periodic updates forces the table to use a natural key. And so I'll have to migrate my database schema.)

I have a production database with a table like *planets*, which although it has good potential natural keys (e.g., the planet names which never really change), uses a typical incremented integer as the primary key. The planets table has a self-referencing column or two such as *parent_planet_id*.

Now I'm building offline cloud-based workers that re-create subsets of the planets records each week, and they need to be integrated with the main server. My plan is:

- A worker instance has a mini version of the database (same schema, but no planets records)
- Once per week, the worker fires up, does all its processing, creates its 100,000 or so planets records, and exports the data. (I don't think the export format matters for this particular problem: could be mysqldump, yaml, etc.)
- Then, the production server imports the records: some are new records, most are updates.

This last step is what I don't know how to solve. I'm not entirely replacing the planets table each time, so the problem is that the two databases each have their own incrementing integer PK's. And so I can't just do a simple import.

I thought about exporting without the id column, but then I realized that the self-referencing columns prevent this.

I see two possible solutions:

- Redesign the schema to use a natural key for the planets table. This would be a pain.
- Use UUID instead of an incrementing integer for the key. Would be easier, I think, to move to. The id's would be unique, and the new rows could be safely imported. This also avoids the issues with depending on natural data in keys.

Comment: Will you ever need to UPDATE a planet that already exists in the "master" database, or you'll always just INSERT?

Comment: Most operations are updates...

Answer (score 1):

Modify the `Planets` to use alternate-hierarchy technique, like **[nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)**,  **closure table**, or **path enumeration** and than export. This will break the ID-dependency.

Or, if you still do not like the idea, consider your export and import as an ETL problem.

- Modify the record during the export to include `PlanetName, ParentPlanetName`
- Import all Planets (`PlanetNames`) first
- Then import the hierarchy (`ParentPlanetName`)

In any case, the surrogate key from the first DB should never leave that DB -- it has no meaning outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution (in terms of desing) would be to refine your keys architecture and implement some composite key having info about when and from where the planets were imported, but you do not want to do this.

Easier (I think), and yet a bit "happy engineering" solution would be to modify importing keys. You can do this for example like that:
1. lock planets table in main system (so no new key will appear during import),
2. create lookup table having two columns, ID and PLANET NAME basing on planet table in main system,
3. get the maximum key value from that table,
4. increment every imported key (identyfying and referencing the parent-child planet relationship) value by adding the MAX value retrived within step #3,
5. alter main planet table and change current auto increment value for actual MAX + 1 value
6. now go over the table (cursor loop within procedure) checking if for the current planet name you have different key in your lookup, if yes first remove the record from the table with the key from lookup (the old one) and update the key value within the currently inspected row for an old id (that was an update),
7. unlock the table.

Answer (score 0):

> Most operations are updates

So you need a "real" merge. In other words, you'll have to identify a proper **order** in which you can INSERT/UPDATE the data, so no FKs are violated in the process.

I'm not sure what `parent_planet_id` means, but assuming it means "orbits" and the word "planet" is stretched to also include moons, imagine you have only Phobos in your master database and Mars and Deimos need to be imported. This can only be done in a certain order:

1. INSERT Mars.
2. INSERT Deimos, set its `parent_planet_id` so it points to Mars.
3. UPDATE Phobos' `parent_planet_id` so it points to Mars.

While you could exchange steps (2) and (3), you couldn't do either before the step (1).

You'll need a recursive descent to determine the proper order and then compare natural keys<sup>1</sup> to see what needs to be UPDATEd and what INSERTed. Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support recursive queries, so you'll need to do it manually.

I don't quite see how surrogate keys help in this process - if anything, they add one more level of indirection you'll have to reconcile eventually.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Which, unlike surrogates, are meaningful across different databases. You can't just compare auto-incremented integers because the same integer value might identify different planets in different databases - you'll have false UPDATEs. GUIDs, on the other hand, will never match, even when rows describe the same planet - you'll have false INSERTs.*